# How does "sharing" of purchased apps work on iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod.app

If I buy an app for iPad or iPhone, then login to my account on a few other iPhones and download that app, are there any restrictions on how many devices I can install that application on?

Once I've downloaded the app to the maximum amount of devices, will my restriction be lifted if I delete the app on those devices?

Basically, how exactly does installing apps, with the same account, on multiple devices work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a limit to this (or there isn't yet a limit that is imposed by Apple); you should be able to install iOS apps that you purchase on *all* your iOS devices (obviously using the same Apple ID).

From the [Apple iTunes Terms of Service](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html):

> APP STORE PRODUCT USAGE RULES
>
> (i) If you are an individual acting in your personal capacity, you may download and sync an App Store Product for personal, noncommercial use on any iOS Device you own or control.